# Trying to make a working spring for a car, however the bones and linear weight gradient aren't working as intended

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

I've been trying to make a working spring that expands and detracts depending on the bone position. Following a tutorial on youtube, I attached a linear weight gradient to the spring, but when I move the bone, it "squashes" the middle part, which is not the desired effect. -

[image]

Here's the weight gradient I put onto the spring below.

[image]

Is there anyway I can get this desired effect below where the spring doesn't deform itself in the middle?

[image]

Thanks for any pointers or advice. Sorry if I didn't make this clear enough.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Do the other vertex groups have any weights? My guess is the other bones are having some influence that they shouldn't be.

Comment: you will probably need more bones to animate a spring, you could also do it with shapekeys as explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=726ADNZeX3c&feature=emb_logo